# How to build a range slider with gradient border?

Tags: css

I have a range slider that has a gradient background line to slide on and I want ***the slider thumb to have the same gradient as border.***

I understand normally this could be achieved with a pseudo element (before / after) but given that we are already using one for the thumb, I'm not sure how to achieve this. Would anyone know?

Many thanks in advance!

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/AlphaX/1c35ot6r/)**

```css
.gdas-range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee, #36b7ee) !important; /* For Chrome and Safari */
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee, #36b7ee) !important; /* For old Fx (3.6 to 15) */
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee, #36b7ee) !important; /* For pre-releases of IE 10*/
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee, #36b7ee) !important; /* For old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */
  background-image:         linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee, #36b7ee) !important; /* Standard syntax; must be last */
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.gdas-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #757575;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gdas-range::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #757575;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <span class="gdas-menu-left"><input type="range" name="gdas-range" class="gdas-range"></span>
```

Comment: Please provide codepen or similar

Comment: I added a JSFIDDLE :-)

Comment: There is no way to do this with CSS alone. You need a JavaScript function that gets the value of your input on `change` event, calculate and apply correct color to knob based on value. If you don't provide your own coding attempt at it and specify what it is that's not working/not clear, your *"question"* is simply a *"I need free coding services for free"* type of request.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu ok thank you Andrei, that's already helpful to know and a sufficient answer to my problem, i.e. it's just not possible with CSS.

Comment: can you be more precise on where you want the gradient to be ?

Comment: @AlphaX, you're welcome. A "decent" solution, from where I see it, is to apply middle color (`#36b7ee`) to both background and border of knob. That's what I'd do. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/1c35ot6r/4/).

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hi Temani! The round thumb has a 1px #757575 border, which I actually would like to be gradient instead. Ideally (but not must have) the border would even pick up the sliding colour of the background line, but when researching I have seen such solutions only with JS, so I think it's not possible just with CSS.

Comment: and what about the below solution ?

Comment: It didnt work righ away , but got it now! Thanks for checking in Temani! Have a great evening!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the background image of the thumb share the space reference of the slider using

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #7b63f0, #7b63f0, #3ad4c1, #36b7ee, #36b7ee);
 background-attachment: fixed;
```

it's the bkg-attachment that does the magic

```css
.gdas-range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, green);
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.gdas-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
     background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(to right, red, green);
     background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
     background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}

.gdas-range::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
     background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(to right, red, green);
     background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
     background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<span class="gdas-menu-left"><input type="range" name="gdas-range" class="gdas-range"></span>
```

Comment: changing the second border 1px solid #757575 also to transparent made it work for me! thanks!!

Comment: Sorry, I copied the Chrome code to the FF one, and forgot this line !